# How to consume a dotnet console application from a Nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-core

**The scenario is as follows:**

a) An arbitrary MyProject.csproj invokes MyConsoleApp.exe as part of a post build event.

b) MyConsoleApp.exe is packaged and consumed via Nuget with all its dependencies

I am not convinced this is the "dotnet core 2.0" way of doing things, I tried dotnet pack MyConsoleApp.csproj but that doesn't include the dependencies like the .exe file does. Should it include all references in a nupkg and publish the package at build time?

**MyProject.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...
  <Target Name="GenerateSomeFiles" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="dotnet run MyConsoleApp.dll $(TargetDir)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try running dotnet publish, then running dotnet pack against the publish folder that's created under bin/Release or bin/Debug.

If you still want an exe, you should either setup a target Runtime for x86/x64 in your csproj, or setup multi-targeting for a full framework version.